# Is it possible to have a view and viewmodel without a model?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

When I read this line:

The viewmodel exposes not only models, but other properties (such as state information, like the "is busy" indicator) and commands.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/100175/Model-View-ViewModel-MVVM-Explained

I am wondering whether current settings on the view should be considered a property of the view or part of the state and placed in a view model.

For example I currently have a preferences window bound to a view model containing the current colors with a bunch of color pickers bound to the view model. Commands then cancel changes and reapply the old settings if ok or cancel are clicked.

Should the current colors be properties on the view instead or is their current location ok?

```
public class PreferencesWindowViewModel:DependencyObject
  {
    private DelegateCommand updatePreferencesCommand;

    public ICommand UpdatePreferencesCommand
    {
      get { return updatePreferencesCommand; }
    }
    private DelegateCommand cancelCommand;

    public ICommand CancelCommand
    {
      get { return cancelCommand; }
    }

    public Color HighValuePenColor
    {
      get { return (Color)GetValue(HighValuePenColorProperty); }
      set
      {
        SetValue(HighValuePenColorProperty, value);
      }
    }
```

Comment: [Don't use `DependencyObjects` for ViewModels](http://kentb.blogspot.com.ar/2009/03/view-models-pocos-versus.html)

Comment: yeah i noticed that recently while looking over an article discussing dependencyobjects vs inotifypropertychanged. I haven't gone back and changed them all yet though

Answer (score 1):

I like them to be on the view model. For the simple reason that this functionality is testable in a unit testing harness. If they were on the view you would have to jump through so many more hoops to get it tested. In my opinion, the view model should contain most of the presentation logic. Colors and their relation to certain application states belong in that category of code.